# Cast column containing multiple string date formats to DateTime in Spark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a date column in my Spark `DataDrame` that contains multiple string formats. I would like to cast these to DateTime.

The two formats in my column are:

- `mm/dd/yyyy`; and
- `yyyy-mm-dd`

My solution so far is to use a UDF to change the first date format to match the second as follows:

```
import re

def parseDate(dateString):
    if re.match('\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}', dateString) is not None:
        return datetime.strptime(dateString, '%M/%d/%Y').strftime('%Y-%M-%d')
    else:
        return dateString

# Create Spark UDF based on above function
dateUdf = udf(parseDate)

df = (df.select(to_date(dateUdf(raw_transactions_df['trans_dt']))))
```

This works, but is not all that fault-tolerant. I am specifically concerned about:

- Date formats I am yet to encounter.
- Distinguishing between `mm/dd/yyyy` and `dd/mm/yyyy` (the regex I'm using clearly doesn't do this at the moment).

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Personally I would recommend using SQL functions directly without expensive and inefficient reformatting:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import coalesce, to_date

def to_date_(col, formats=("MM/dd/yyyy", "yyyy-MM-dd")):
    # Spark 2.2 or later syntax, for < 2.2 use unix_timestamp and cast
    return coalesce(*[to_date(col, f) for f in formats])
```

This will choose the first format, which can successfully parse input string.

Usage:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([(1, "01/22/2010"), (2, "2018-12-01")], ("id", "dt"))
df.withColumn("pdt", to_date_("dt")).show()
```

```
+---+----------+----------+
| id|        dt|       pdt|
+---+----------+----------+
|  1|01/22/2010|2010-01-22|
|  2|2018-12-01|2018-12-01|
+---+----------+----------+
```

It will be faster than `udf`, and adding new formats is just a matter of adjusting `formats` parameter.

However it won't help you with format ambiguities. In general case it might not be possible to do it without manual intervention and cross referencing with external data.

The same thing can be of course done in Scala:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Column
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{coalesce, to_date}

def to_date_(col: Column, 
             formats: Seq[String] = Seq("MM/dd/yyyy", "yyyy-MM-dd")) = {
  coalesce(formats.map(f => to_date(col, f)): _*)
}
```

Comment: I am using the same code but with Seq("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss", "dd-MM-yyyy H:mm:ss").. Whenever I get a record with the format  "dd-MM-yyyy H:mm:ss" - second one in Seq. It throws error, value cannot be parsed. Date column has same format but when hour is smaller thatn 10, it is represented as single digit - like 9 and not 09.

Comment: please look at this question detailing the same: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75315732/multiple-formats-in-date-time-column-in-spark

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in 100% sql with something like this:

```
create database delete_me;
use delete_me;
create table test (enc_date string);

insert into test values ('10/28/2019');
insert into test values ('2020-03-31 00:00:00.000');
insert into test values ('2019-10-18');
insert into test values ('gobledie-gook');
insert into test values ('');
insert into test values (null);
insert into test values ('NULL');

-- you might need the following line depending on your version of spark
-- set spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy = LEGACY;
select enc_date, coalesce(to_date(enc_date, "yyyy-MM-dd"), to_date(enc_date, "MM/dd/yyyy")) as date from test;


enc_date                    date
--------                    ----
2020-03-31 00:00:00.000     2020-03-31
2019-10-18                  2019-10-18
null                        null
10/28/2019                  2019-10-28
gobledie-gook               null
NULL                        null
                            null
```

Answer (score 0):

use **to_timestamp()**, and i believe the issues is from the time format rule, for example your data is like:
[image: sample data]

[image]

And please pay attention on the difference like "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss","dd:MM:yyyy HH:mm:ss", see the compare below:
[image]

Comment: spark version is 3.0.1