# How to change date format in Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following DataFrame:

```
+----------+-------------------+
| timestamp|            created|
+----------+-------------------+
|1519858893|2018-03-01 00:01:33|
|1519858950|2018-03-01 00:02:30|
|1519859900|2018-03-01 00:18:20|
|1519859900|2018-03-01 00:18:20|
```

How to create a timestamp correctly`?

I was able to create `timestamp` column which is epoch timestamp, but dates to not coincide:

```
df.withColumn("timestamp",unix_timestamp($"created"))
```

For example, `1519858893` points to `2018-02-28`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `date_format` and `to_utc_timestamp` *inbuilt functions*

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
df.withColumn("timestamp", to_utc_timestamp(date_format(col("created"), "yyy-MM-dd"), "Asia/Kathmandu"))
```

Comment: Based on using this approach, how can I filter out all timestamps or dates that are earlier than current date?

Comment: if you want to filter out all the rows earlier than current date then do `.filter($"timestamp" >= current_date())` I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
df.withColumn("dateColumn", df("timestamp").cast(DateType))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check one solution here https://stackoverflow.com/a/46595413
To elaborate more on that with the dataframe having different formats of timestamp/date in string, you can do this -

```
val df = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq("2020-04-21 10:43:12.000Z", "20-04-2019 10:34:12", "11-30-2019 10:34:12", "2020-05-21 21:32:43", "20-04-2019", "2020-04-21")).toDF("ts")

def strToDate(col: Column): Column = {
    val formats: Seq[String] = Seq("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:SS", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:SS", "dd-MM-yyyy", "yyyy-MM-dd")
    coalesce(formats.map(f => to_timestamp(col, f).cast(DateType)): _*)
  }

val formattedDF = df.withColumn("dt", strToDate(df.col("ts")))

formattedDF.show()
+--------------------+----------+
|                  ts|        dt|
+--------------------+----------+
|2020-04-21 10:43:...|2020-04-21|
| 20-04-2019 10:34:12|2019-04-20|
| 2020-05-21 21:32:43|2020-05-21|
|          20-04-2019|2019-04-20|
|          2020-04-21|2020-04-21|
+--------------------+----------+
```

**Note**: - This code assumes that data does not contain any column of format -> MM-dd-yyyy, MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:SS