# incorrect timestamp csv parsing by spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-zeppelin

I have a CSV file formatted like this :

```
574,REF009,3213,16384,3258,111,512,2013-12-07 21:03:12.567+01,2013-12-07 21:03:12.567+01,2013-12-31 23:33:15.821+01,/data/ath/athdisk/ro/user/bas/b6/c0
48,REF010,456,32768,3258,111,2175850,2018-07-10 04:37:06.495+02,2018-07-10 04:37:06.459+02,2018-07-10 04:37:06.648+02,/data/ath/athdisk/ro/mc15/b9/dc/lo.log.tgz.1
1758,REF011,123,32768,3258,111,31691926,2017-04-21 22:29:30.315+02,2017-10-20 05:55:03.959+02,2017-04-21 22:29:31+02,/data/ath/athdisk/ro/dataV/1f/00/D0293.pool.root
```

When trying to import this massive (11B lines long) files I had around 4M lines full of null value. I realize that my file was having issues so I tried to run the import with option FAILFAST like this :

```
val inodes_schema = StructType(
    Array(
        StructField("testID",LongType,false),
        StructField("ref",StringType,false),
        StructField("iref",IntegerType, false),
        StructField("flag",IntegerType, false),
        StructField("iuid",IntegerType, false),
        StructField("igid",IntegerType, false),
        StructField("isize",LongType, false),
        StructField("icrtime",TimestampType,false),
        StructField("iatime",TimestampType,false),
        StructField("ictime",TimestampType,false),
        StructField("path",StringType,false)
    )
)

val inodes_table = spark.read.option("mode", "FAILFAST")
.option("timestampFormat", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSX")
.schema(inodes_schema)
.option("delimiter",",")
.option("header",false).csv("/my/csv/file.csv")
```

This allows me to identify that the line containing `59+02` was causing the issue. Having a lot of line containing `59+02`, I finally manage to identify  one as not properly imported if I use usual `PERMISSIVE` mode :

```
 1758,REF011,123,32768,3258,111,31691926,2017-04-21 22:29:30.315+02,2017-10-20 05:55:03.959+02,2017-04-21 22:29:31+02,/data/ath/athdisk/ro/dataV/1f/00/D0293.pool.root
```

I don't understand why is this line not properly parsed by Spark?  `05:55:03.959+02` hour format is correct regarding my timestamp, yet line will not be properly imported and probably a lot of them.

Comment: You have two different formats, so using single format input, doesn't look like the right  approach. Shouldn't you rather try something [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46594750/8371915)?

Comment: @user8371915 My file contains millions of record and both 2 digit or 3 on miliseond works but some don't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The said problem appears to be caused by having multiple timestamp formats in your data.  A work-around is to make the TimestampType columns StringType for reading the CSV and cast them back to TimestampType afterward:

```
// /path/to/csvfile:
1,2017-04-21 22:29:30.315+02
2,2017-10-20 05:55:03.959+02
3,2017-04-21 22:29:31+02

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

val schema = StructType(Array(
  StructField("id", IntegerType, false),
  StructField("dt", StringType, false)
))

val df = spark.read.
  option("mode", "FAILFAST").
  option("delimiter", ",").
  option("header", false).
  schema(schema).
  csv("/path/to/csvfile")

df.select($"id", $"dt".cast(TimestampType)as("dt")).
  show(false)
// +---+-----------------------+
// |id |dt                     |
// +---+-----------------------+
// |1  |2017-04-21 13:29:30.315|
// |2  |2017-10-19 20:55:03.959|
// |3  |2017-04-21 13:29:31    |
// +---+-----------------------+
```