# Multiple formats in Date Time column in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am using Spark3.0.1

I have following data as csv:

348702330256514,37495066290,9084849,33946,614677375609919,11-02-2018 0:00:00,GENUINE
348702330256514,37495066290,330148,33946,614677375609919,11-02-2018 00:00:00,GENUINE
348702330256514,37495066290,136052,33946,614677375609919,11-02-2018 0:00:00,GENUINE
348702330256514,37495066290,4310362,33946,614677375609919,11-02-2018 00:00:00,GENUINE
348702330256514,37495066290,9097094,33946,614677375609919,11-02-2018 0:00:00,GENUINE
348702330256514,37495066290,2291118,33946,614677375609919,11-02-2018 00:00:00,GENUINE
348702330256514,37495066290,4900011,33946,614677375609919,11-02-2018 0:00:00,GENUINE
348702330256514,37495066290,633447,33946,614677375609919,11-02-2018 0:00:00,GENUINE
348702330256514,37495066290,6259303,33946,614677375609919,11-02-2018 0:00:00,GENUINE
348702330256514,37495066290,369067,33946,614677375609919,11-02-2018 0:00:00,GENUINE
348702330256514,37495066290,1193207,33946,614677375609919,11-02-2018 0:00:00,GENUINE
348702330256514,37495066290,9335696,33946,614677375609919,11-02-2018 0:00:00,GENUINE

As you can see the **second last column has Timestamp data** where the **hour column will have data both in single as well as double digits**, depending on the hour of the day (This is sample data and not all records have all zeros for time part).

This is the problem and I tried to solve the problem as below:

Read the column as String and then Use a column Method to format it to TimeStamp type.

```scala
  val schema = StructType(
    List(
        StructField("_corrupt_record", StringType)
        ,   StructField("card_id", LongType)
        , StructField("member_id", LongType)
        , StructField("amount", IntegerType)
        , StructField("postcode", IntegerType)
        , StructField("pos_id", LongType)
        , StructField("transaction_dt", StringType)
        , StructField("status", StringType)
    )       
  )
  

// format the timestamp column
def format_time_column(timeStampCol: Column
            , formats: Seq[String] = Seq( "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss", "dd-MM-yyyy H:mm:ss"
                    , "dd-MM-yyyy HH:m:ss", "dd-MM-yyyy H:m:ss")) ={
        coalesce(
                formats.map(f => to_timestamp(timeStampCol, f)):_*
                
        ) 
    }

val cardTransaction = spark.read
    .format("csv")
    .option("header", false)
    .schema(schema)
    .option("path", cardTransactionFilePath)
    .option("columnNameOfCorruptRecord", "_corrupt_record")
    .load
    .withColumn("transaction_dt", format_time_column(col("transaction_dt")))


cardTransaction.cache()
cardTransaction.show(5)
```

This code produces following **error**:

[image]

***Note**:

1. The record highlighted has only 1 digit for hour
2. Whatever is the first format provided in the list of formats, only that works all the rest formats are not considered.
3. Problem is that to_timestamp() throws exception instead of producing null as is expected by coalesce(), when wrong format is encounterd.

How to solve it?

Comment: Is it Spark 2.X or 3.X?

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text/data/code/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/15405732). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question/answer. If you select it and click the {} button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code. Please edit your question to turn the image into well-formatted text.

Comment: @M_S Spark 3.0.1. I will edit the question.

Comment: @Koedlt I have removed the image and pasted raw csv data. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @VivekPuurkayastha thanks for helping to make your post better! Just one last thing: please add your error stack trace as well-formatted text too. This really helps for people with the same problem as you in the future to be able to find this post with search engines. If you want to refer to a specific line in your stack trace, you can just type it again (instead of highlighting). Thanks a bunch :)

Answer (score 0):

- In Spark 3.0, we define our own pattern strings in Datetime Patterns for Formatting and Parsing, which is implemented via DateTimeFormatter under the hood.
- In Spark version 2.4 and below, java.text.SimpleDateFormat is used for timestamp/date string conversions, and the supported patterns are described in SimpleDateFormat.
- The old behavior can be restored by setting spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy to LEGACY.

```
sparkConf.set("spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy","LEGACY")
```

Doc:
[sql-migration-guide.html#query-engine](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.1/sql-migration-guide.html#query-engine)

Comment: Thanks. This works. But I still have problem understanding why the exception because in format_time_column function the coalesce functin should be handling that. Any idea?

Comment: Sorry about the weekend, missed it.
I think the idea is spark3 have used `DateTimeFormatter`, but spark2 used `SimpleDateFormat`.
You can try this code:
`
final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
final Date parse1 = sdf.parse("11-02-2018 0:00:00");
`
It works.
But
`DateTimeFormatter dtf1 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
dtf1.parse("11-02-2018 0:00:00");`
It's the exception which you get.